# Get correct selection with VSCode extension when user navigates to new document

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension that subscribes to `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor`. If `Go to definition` is used, the `TextEditor` received by `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` will report a `selection` of `0,0`. The "correct" selection is transported in a separate event (`onDidChangeTextEditorSelection`).

The `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` event seems to originate from `textFileEditors.ts`:

```
textEditor.setModel(textFileModel.textEditorModel);
```

The selection is updated shortly afterwards:

```
// Apply options to editor if any
if (options) {
    applyTextEditorOptions(options, textEditor, ScrollType.Immediate);
}
```

Even if flipped around, this has no impact, because the new selection is transported in an internal event that will not reach the code before the `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` event is sent to the extension host.

Is there a way for an extension to know if the new editor is opened at `0,0` or another position without waiting to see if the selection is updated shortly after?

The events for opening a editor at (0,0) are:

- `didOpenTextDocument`
- `didChangeActiveTextEditor`

The events for opening an editor at any other position are:

- `didOpenTextDocument`
- `didChangeActiveTextEditor` (position is (0,0))
- `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection` (position is the "correct" position)

Comment: if you depend on the current selection than only use `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection` and use the current editor in that event handler

Comment: @rioV8 that only works if the user opens the file at a position != (0,0). If the user opens at (0,0) the `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection` is not triggered. That is the core of my question: How to know the correct position without waiting?